# fluent ffmpeg how to set X11 display as input

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, x11, xvfb, fluent-ffmpeg

With command line i can easily capture an Xserver display, trying to reproduce this with fluent-ffmpeg for node

```
videoCommand.addInput(':99.0+0,150')
.withSize('720x480')
.withFpsInput(60)
.withFpsOutput(60)
.addInputOption('-y', '-f x11grab')
.outputOptions(['-c:v libx264', '-crf 18' , '-preset veryfast' , '-t 
 00:00:05'])
.output(base_path+'/video.mp4')
.run();
```

I get

```
Unrecognized option 'f x11grab'.
```

I am concerned about the syntax or way to set the input as DISPLAY :99.0
and also to tell ffmpeg that i want x11grab.

Where those has to be set ?

--- EDIT ---

changed to   .addInputOptions('-y', '-f x11grab')
with 's'

same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked like this :

```
videoCommand.addInput(':99.0+0,150')
.withSize('720x480')
.withFpsInput(60)
.withFpsOutput(60)
.addInputOptions('-y', '-f' , 'x11grab')
.outputOptions(['-c:v libx264', '-crf 18' , '-preset veryfast' , '-t 
00:00:05'])
.output(base_path+'/video.mp4')
.run();
```

trick was here :

```
.addInputOptions('-y', '-f' , 'x11grab')
```

options needs to be separated